# SWRL for choosing the right value?

Tags: owl, swrl

I'm trying to create an ontology of latin squares and make the reasoner solve it (starting with a simple 2x2 square and going from there) without much success.

The major problem I'm having is writing a rule in a way that sees what values are missing from the square.
I'm using dataProperty **hasValue** as an integer.
Something like:

```
Cell(?cell1) ^ hasValue(?cell1,?number1) ^ 
Cell(?cell2) ^ hasValue(?cell2,?number2) ^ 
Cell(?cell3) ^ hasValue(?cell3,?number3) ^
Cell(?cell4) ^ differentFrom(?number1, ?number2)
=>
hasValue(?Cell4,"desired result")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the head of the rule you wrote `?Cell4` but in the body you're using `?cell4` . Is it just a typo here? Do you get an error? How do you apply the SWRL rule? Which reasoner or API do you use? Can you share instance data?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo. I'm using hermit reasoner. I don't get an error as I don't know how to complete the right side of the rule.

Comment: Have you looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44004882/protege-owl-class-must-have-one-of-each-value)? There was also file named 'sudaku.owl' somewhere in Pellet forks on Github.